How to add some vertical space in ConTeXt
In LaTeX, I used this:
Some text\\[1pt] Some more text.

In ConTeXt, I cannot find a way to do the same thing. Somebody suggested using a blank, but then the second line is indented for me, and starts way lower than it should (even with \break[0mm]. Right now, simply using \ is the closest I can get to what I’m looking for, but it’s definitely not ideal. Is there any way to implement this. I do not think break will work for this.
The point is to separate the question from the answer a bit, here:

Compare what I had in LaTeX (the difference is very subtle, but it’s much more comfortable for the eye

Here’s what it looks like with \blank:

And with \blank[0mm]:


Is \blank (or \vspacing) what you look for? Usually that is built in to some environment. Please show your code.

Have you considered using the description mechanism for the question blocks?

@mickep it still goes to far down, see the update in the post.

@mickep here’s the code for those two lines I had in LaTeX:
\italic{Qu’osa-t-il après cela ?}\[1pt] Il fit un écrit de 95 articles qu’il attacha aux portes de l’église de Wittemberg.
\italic{Que contenaient ces articles ?}\[1pt] Bien des choses qui ne raccordaient nullement avec l’ancienne doctrine de l’Église.

@WolfgangSchuster This seems like a possibility, unfortunately, I’m pretty new to ConTeXt, and I see no option to arrange the two vertically, the mechanism as a understand it only accounts for horizontal placement

In order to get help, you should provide the complete code of this minimal example. It is considered a bit rude to assume that others shall type everything just to help you. Also, it is very seldom that you should have to add spaces manually in ConTeXt.

@mickep The example itself is irrelevant, I just put the screenshots in to demonstrate visually why I want to do that. If there is any solution, it could just as easily be demonstrated on "Lorem ipsum (some function here) dolor sit amet"

Your example looks like something which is best set with the description mechanism where you can set different styles for the title and content.
\define[1]\QuestionTitle
  {\offset[x=-1em]{#1}}

\definedescription
  [Question]
  [alternative=top,
        margin=1em,
        align=verytolerant,
    headstyle=italic,
  headcommand=\QuestionTitle,
        before={\blank[medium]},
        after={\blank[medium]},
    inbetween={\blank[small]}]

\mainlanguage[fr]

\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]

%\showframe
%\showgrid

\starttext

\startQuestion[title={Qu’osa-t-il après cela?}]
Il fit un écrit de 95 articles qu’il attacha aux portes de l’église de Wittemberg.
\stopQuestion

\startQuestion[title={Que contenaient ces articles?}]
Bien des choses qui ne raccordaient nullement avec l’ancienne doctrine de l’Église.
\stopQuestion

\stoptext


Just to show how to get what you are used to with LaTeX:
\starttext
{\it Qu’osa-t-il ?}\\\blank[1pt]Il fit un écrit\\
{\it Qu’osa-t-il ?}  \blank[1pt]Il fit un écrit\\
%                  ^ diff here
%                    no need for \\
%                    \blank is in charge of
\stoptext

